# Adding Dropdown to Register.cshtml in Identity

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I am using Microsoft Identity in my Asp.NET MVC Core 7.0 application with a customized `IdentityUser`:

```cs
public class SparkleWebAppUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must provide a user name")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "User name cannot be longer than 15 letters")]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public override string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must provide first name")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longetr than 20 letters")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must provide last name")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 20 letters")]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must provide a parent id to continue. Please contact your company/organisation to get parents id.")]
    [Display(Name = "Your Organization's ID")]
    public int OrgId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must mention type of application user")]
    //[ForeignKey("UserType")]
    public AppUserType AppUserType { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<AppUserType> SelectedAppUserType { get; set; }

    public virtual WorkLocation? OfficeName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must provide Id Number provided to you by your organization")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Your personal ID in the organization")]
    public string IdNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;


    [Display(Name = "Profile Picture")]
    public byte[]? ProfilePic { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName { get { return (FirstName + " " + LastName); } }
}
```

below is the model of `AppUserType`:

```cs
public class AppUserType
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 15 letters")]
    [Display(Name = "User Type Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    [Display(Name = "App Users")]
    public ICollection<SparkleWebAppUser>? lIMISAppUsers { get; set; }

}
```

The `Register` in `Identity` is given below:

```html
@page
@using iStar.Sparkle.WebDev.Areas.Identity.Models;
@model RegisterModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "New User Sign Up";
    //Layout = "~/Areas/Identity/Views/Shared/_IdentityLayout.cshtml";
}



<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="registerForm" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger" role="alert"></div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.UserName" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                <label asp-for="Input.UserName">User Name</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                <label asp-for="Input.FirstName">First Name</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.LastName" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                <label asp-for="Input.LastName">Last Name</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.OrgId" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                <label asp-for="Input.OrgId">Company ID</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.OrgId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.OfficeName" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                <label asp-for="Input.OfficeName">Company's Office Name</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.OfficeName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
@*            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.AppUserType" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                <label asp-for="Input.AppUserType">Access Type</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.AppUserType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>*@
            
            
            
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                @*<select asp-for="Input.AppUserType" asp-items="@(new SelectList(AppUserType, "Id", "Name"))" value="Id">Access Type</select>*@
                @*<input asp-for="Input.AppUserType" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />*@
                <label asp-for="Input.AppUserType">Access Type</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.AppUserType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            
            
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Email">Email</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Password">Password</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button id="registerSubmit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <section>
            <h3>Use another service to register.</h3>
            <hr />
            @{
                if ((Model.ExternalLogins?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
                {
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            There are no external authentication services configured. See this <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">article
                            about setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services</a>.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins!)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

I want to use a drop down *SelectItemList* for AppUserType in the **Register** page. I have tried several ways but none is working. The last one mentioned here

```html
<div class="form-group mb-3">
                <select asp-for="Input.AppUserType" asp-items="@(new SelectList(AppUserType, "Id", "Name"))" value="Id">Access Type</select>
                @*<input asp-for="Input.AppUserType" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />*@
                <label asp-for="Input.AppUserType">Access Type</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.AppUserType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

looks quite sensible but I don't know how can I fill the drop down from table 'AppUserTypes' in this dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Is your dropdown's value from a database table?

You can try to create a property into the RegisterModel:

```
[BindProperty]
public SelectList DropDown { get; set; }
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    DropDown = new SelectList(_context.AppUserType.ToList(),"Id","Name");
    //...
}
```

And in Register.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
     <select asp-for="Input.AppUserType" aria-required="true" asp-items="@Model.DropDown" value="Id">Access Type</select>
     @*<input asp-for="Input.AppUserType" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />*@
     <label asp-for="Input.AppUserType">Access Type</label>
     <span asp-validation-for="Input.AppUserType" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this .... but its not working too

Comment: Is the dropdown not loading or something else? @Fayyaz Ahmed

Comment: dropdown is not loading. @Chen

Comment: Is there a value in the `DropDown` property? What is it like? @Fayyaz Ahmed

Comment: No, dropdown appears on the page but it does not contain any value. can i share any screenshot or entire project with you? @Chen

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the final look of the `DropDown` property? Does the value exist in your `AppUserType` database table? @Fayyaz Ahmed

Comment: i can't see any option here to share images. better if you share your email. I shall share images and files with you. @Chen